# Product rule in discrete derivative in finite difference scheme.

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose we are on real line and I want to discretize the usual derivative operator. Take a smooth function $u$ and step size $h$. Then I could define
$$
\Delta_+u(i) = \frac{u(i+1)-u(i)}{h}
$$
as the discrete form of derivative. Here $i$ is an integer.

Now my question is, when I try to compute $\Delta_+(u(i)\cdot v(i))$, should I have
$$
\Delta_+(u(i)\cdot v(i)) = \frac{u(i+1)v(i+1)-u(i)v(i)}{h} \tag 1
$$
or should I have a sort of product rule and obtain
$$
\Delta_+(u(i)\cdot v(i)) = \Delta_+u(i)\cdot v(i)+u(i)\Delta_+v(i).
$$
Which one is correct? Or which one is better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one is correct by definition. One can try to get a product rule as
$$
\Delta_+(u(i)\cdot v(i))=\frac{u(i+1)v(i+1)-u(i)v(i+1)+u(i)v(i+1)-u(i)v(i)}{h}=\\
=\Delta_+(u(i))\cdot v(\color{red} {i+1})+u(i)\cdot\Delta_+v(i)
$$
but you see the difference in indexing.

Comment: That's an asymmetric formula based on what appears to be the symmetric discrete derivative of the multiplication of two functions.  Could you explain?

Comment: @abiessu It is the *forward* difference, not symmetric. Symmetric would be something like $\Delta u(i)=\frac{u(i+1)-u(i-1)}{2h}$.

Comment: I'm not saying the difference is symmetric, but the multiplication of two functions should be.  So I'm asking about the $v(i+1)$ vs. $u(i)$ difference in the final formula...  But you're right, I said "symmetric discrete derivative" when I should have said "discrete derivative of the symmetric multiplication of two functions"...

Comment: @abiessu If one wants to have a symmetric formula for the product rule of forward differences then one has to add *higher order* terms e.g. $\Delta_+(u\cdot v)=\Delta_+(u)v+u\Delta_+(v)+\color{blue}{\Delta_+(u)\Delta(v)}$. In the product rule for derivatives the point $i+1$ glues together with $i$ after taking the limit, that's why the rule looks symmetric.

Comment: And that is what I wanted you to expound upon in your answer.  Thank you!

Comment: Yea @A.Γ. s formula is the right way to go, this can be  readily generalized to arbitrary step-size and reduces to the normal product rule from calculus when the step size goes to 0.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stumbles upon this but wants to do a finite difference with a different step size. Given an arbitrary difference operator

$$ D_{h,x} [f] = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} $$

Where that $h$ need not even be a number, it could be another explicit function. We have the following product rule

$$ D_{h,x} [f*g] = D_{h,x}[f]g + fD_{h,x}[g] + hD_{h,x}[f]D_{h,x}[g] $$

Setting $h=1$ gives you the formula you are looking for. And as a sanity check setting $h=0$ recovers the usual product rule from caculus.