# What is the "best" product rule for finite difference computations?

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics, numerical-calculus

I am currently writing a code for physics modeling, and in it I am computing (spatial) derivatives of some functions, but most importantly : derivatives of products (and quotients) of functions.

In order to compute first order derivatives I use the central difference method :
$$f^\prime (i) \simeq \frac{f(i+1)-f(i-1)}{2\Delta x}$$

We all know the product rule $(fg)^\prime = f^\prime g + f g^\prime$, however, applying the finite difference to the left hand side or the right-hand side we will get very different results :
$$2\Delta x \times (fg)^\prime = f(i+1)g(i+1) - f(i-1)g(i-1)$$
or
$$2\Delta x \times (f^\prime g + f g^\prime) = (f(i+1)-f(i-1)) g(i) + f(i) (g(i+1)-g(i-1))$$

(similar topic : [Product rule in discrete derivative in finite difference scheme.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380354/product-rule-in-discrete-derivative-in-finite-difference-scheme) )

After reading [Numerical differentiation and the product rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092598/numerical-differentiation-and-the-product-rule) , I did understand that both methods are correct, and my guess is that the error obtained from one method or the other is simply different.

However, my questions are : is one or the other is better ? Are there situations where one or the other is better ? Are there any criteria that can tell me which one should I use ? Or should I choose the one I prefer the most, and stick to it ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is not possible to say objectively which is "better" without providing some criterion for quantifying "better."  The first method requires less computational effort; the latter is marginally more accurate (both methods are $O(\Delta x^2)$). It is up to you to decide how to strike a balance between simplicity and accuracy.

Comment: My bad. When I say "better", it is of course in terms of error, but I also was kind of hoping someone with a lot of experience would add some details I might be unaware of.
My model is not that complex, so I would go for accuracy. Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

Having been facing this kind of problems for products and quotients including powers, what I did is the following based on logarithmic differentiation
$$h(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n\big[f_i(x)\big]^{a_i} \implies \log(h(x))=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\log\big[f_i(x)\big]$$
$$\frac {h'(x)}{h(x)}=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\frac{f_i'(x)}{f_i(x)}\implies
{h'(x)}=\Big[ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\frac{f_i'(x)}{f_i(x)}\Big]\,h(x)$$

In $1997$, in the frame of the *Automatic Differentiation Cape Open* project, this was extensively tested and approved.

Comment: This is equivalent to use the second method, i.e. applying the derivative rules first, and then computing the derivatives. I do believe that this method is not wrong, but has it been shown to be "better" ? Do you have any ressource I can read up to get some info ?